# Correct ffmpeg command to get detailed playlist information

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg, streaming

I have a playlist [`playlist.m3u8`] where there are several streams [`https://stream1.m3u8`, `https://stream2.m3u8`], and I would like to get more detailed info of each stream within this playlist.

I tried to run:

```
ffmpeg -fflags -loglevel info -re -i playlist.m3u8 -vcodec copy -acodec copy
```

- Receiving error:

  ```
  Trailing options were found on the commandline.
  playlist.m3u8: Invalid data found when processing input
  ```

How do I write the correct command?

- I need to get output like:

  ```
  Duration: N/A, start: 1672.026833, bitrate: N/A
    Program 0
      Metadata:
        variant_bitrate : 701000
      Stream #0:0: Audio: aac (HE-AACv2), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 63 kb/s
      Metadata:
        variant_bitrate : 701000
        comment         : Multiple languages
      Stream #0:1: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(tv, bt470bg), 854x480 [SAR 1280:1281 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
      Metadata:
        variant_bitrate : 701000
      Stream #0:2(sk): Audio: aac (HE-AACv2) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
      Metadata:
        variant_bitrate : 701000
        comment         : Slovak
    Program 1
      Metadata:
        variant_bitrate : 2001000
      Stream #0:3: Audio: aac (HE-AACv2), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 63 kb/s
      Metadata:
        variant_bitrate : 2001000
        comment         : Multiple languages
      Stream #0:4: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(tv, bt470bg), 1024x576 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
      Metadata:
        variant_bitrate : 2001000
      Stream #0:5(sk): Audio: aac (HE-AACv2) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
      Metadata:
        variant_bitrate : 2001000
        comment         : Slovak
    Program 2
      Metadata:
        variant_bitrate : 3001000
      Stream #0:6: Audio: aac (HE-AACv2), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 63 kb/s
      Metadata:
        variant_bitrate : 3001000
        comment         : Multiple languages
      Stream #0:7: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
      Metadata:
        variant_bitrate : 3001000
      Stream #0:8(sk): Audio: aac (HE-AACv2) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
      Metadata:
        variant_bitrate : 3001000
        comment         : Slovak
    Program 3
      Metadata:
        variant_bitrate : 6001000
      Stream #0:9: Audio: aac (HE-AACv2), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 63 kb/s
      Metadata:
        variant_bitrate : 6001000
        comment         : Multiple languages
      Stream #0:10: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
      Metadata:
        variant_bitrate : 6001000
      Stream #0:11(sk): Audio: aac (HE-AACv2) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
      Metadata:
        variant_bitrate : 6001000
        comment         : Slovak
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Just running `ffmpeg -i playlist.m3u8` will get you the readout.

Answer (score 0):

this is what I get:

`ffmpeg version 4.1.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12) 20160609
  configuration: --prefix=/home/juraj/ffmpeg_build --pkg-config-flags=--static --extra-cflags=-I/home/juraj/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-ldflags=-L/home/juraj/ffmpeg_build/lib --extra-libs='-lpthread -lm' --bindir=/home/juraj/bin --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-vaapi --enable-nonfree
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
playlist.m3u8: No such file or directory`

I am sure that file and directory exist. I am also running this script from the correct directory. I tried even other python scripts from this folder an everything went fine except this ffmpeg command.